# Proving a set closed, bounded, open and non-compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let the set of rational nos. $\mathbb Q$ be a metric space with metric $d(p,q)=|p-q|$. Let $E\subset \mathbb Q$ be such that $E=\{q\in \mathbb Q: 2\lt q^2\lt 3\}$. It's to be shown whether $E$ is open/closed/bounded/compact or not. 
I proceeded as below: 
$E=\{x\in \mathbb Q: -\sqrt 3\lt x\lt -\sqrt2\}\cup \{x\in \mathbb Q: \sqrt 2\lt x\lt \sqrt3\}$

**$E$ is bounded** by definition as $\forall p\in E , |p|\lt 5$

**Claim:** $E$ is open as every point of $E$ is an interior point (take any $x\in E, \exists\delta\gt 0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset E$.

**Proof:** For any $t\in E$, if $t\gt 0$, choose $\delta_t=\min\{t-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3-t\}$

Consider the set $B(t,\delta_t)=\{x\in\mathbb Q: |x-t|\lt \delta_t\}$

For any $s\in B(t,\delta_t), |s-t|\lt \delta_t\implies t-\delta_t\lt s\lt t+\delta_t\implies \sqrt 2\lt s\lt t+\sqrt 3-t\implies \sqrt 2\lt s\lt \sqrt 3\implies s\in E\implies B(t,\delta_t)\subset E\implies t\in E$ is an interior point of $E$. Since $t\gt 0$ is arbitrary, all points $\{t\in E: t\gt 0\}$ of $E$ are interior points of $E$. Similarly for $t\lt 0$. Hence, $E$ is open.

**Claim:** $E$ is closed. .

**Proof:**  We consider $E^c=\mathbb Q- E=\{p\in \mathbb Q: p^2\le 2\}\cup \{p\in \mathbb Q: p^2\ge  3\}=\{p\in \mathbb Q: p^2\lt  2\}\cup \{p\in \mathbb Q: p^2\gt  3\}$

It can be shown here also that $E^c$ is open. Therefore, $E$ is closed.

Let $U_n=\{x\in \mathbb Q: 2+\frac 1n \lt x^2\}$.  Now I claim that $E\subset\cup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$.

**Proof:** $x\in E\implies x^2\gt 2\implies x^2-2\gt 0$. By Archemedean property $\exists k$ such that $x^2-2\gt \frac 1k\implies x\in U_k\subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty U_n\implies E\subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$

**Claim:** $\cup_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ does not have any finite subcover. 
**Proof:** If suppose on the contrary it does then $\exists n_1\lt n_2\lt\cdots\lt n_k$ such that $U_{n_k}\supset U_{n_k-1}\supset \cdots \supset U_1\implies E\in U_{n_k}=\{x\in \mathbb Q: 2+\frac 1{n_k}\lt x^2\}$. Choose $x\in \mathbb Q$ such that $2\lt x^2 \lt 2+\frac 1{n_k}$, then $x\in E$ but $x\notin U_{n_k}$, which is a contradiction and hence our claim is true. 
It follows that $E$ is **not compact.**

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

**Edit:**
**Alternative to prove that $E$ is closed:** It can be shown that $cl(E)=E$ 
Since between any two rational nos. there are infinitely many rational nos., every point of $E$ is a limit point. $E\in cl (E)$. Now let $x\in cl (E)-E$. There are three cases
 1) $x\ge \sqrt 3$: Choose $\delta\lt |x-\sqrt 3|$ so that $(x-\delta, x+\delta)\cap E=\emptyset$ and hence $x$ is not a limit point.
2)$-\sqrt 2\le x \le \sqrt 2$: As in case $(1)$, $x$ is not a limit point. 
3)$ x\le -\sqrt 3$: As in case $(1)$, $x$ is not a limit point of $E$. 
Hence, $cl (E)-E=\emptyset$ and $E\subset cl (E)$ whence it follows that $cl(E)=(cl (E) -E)\cup E=E$.

Comment: Your proofs rely on assumptions that themselves are as strong as the things you are trying to prove. A good example of this is the $E$ is open/closed proofs.

Comment: Well, plus you should want to show that $E$ contains all of its limit points to show that it is closed. This can be handled fairly easily by showing that any limit point of $E$ is some rational number that is between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @DonThousand: I have included more details in my post.

Comment: @MattAPelto: Please refer my edited post.

Comment: Seems good but it would also be nice to see a revised version of your limit point argument. Absolute$0$ has some good ideas in their post for how to use some elementary notions to argue that $E$ is closed and open in $\mathbb{Q}$. I sure hope the person who downvoted their answer isn't one of these deadbeat types too lazy to do anything constructive as I had to upvote their answer just to make it so they weren't being punished for doing something constructive.

Comment: @MattAPelto: I have incorporated my limit point argument.

Comment: I said I'd take a look here, and I'm quite impressed with the attempt. I personally don't see an issue with the attempt, I think everything is correct. The alternative attempt is correct, if a little elaborate maybe.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Many thanks for your review :) Do you want the alternative proof to be elaborated?

Comment: @Koro No no, I was saying that the alternate proof is too long! Haha, I was thinking one doesn't need so many cases, after all in each one you wrote "as in case $(1)$", so it all came back there. It's ok, I guess the other proof is good enough!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon: Okay :) . Thanks a lot Madam. :)

Comment: @Koro: your approach is fine and good to see you learning these concepts. You should try to prove the same thing by using nothing more than properties of rationals. In particular don't use irrationals like $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}$. The proof then is non-obvious and is key to the kind of thinking needed in analysis.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Thanks a lot. Sure! In fact, in the earlier version of the post I had tried to avoid usage of irrationals altogether but then it was being considered incomplete (see the first comment and probably it was incomplete). Last night I even saw one of your posts on this wherein you had considered a rational btw 2 and $x^2$, just as we do when we try to show that $\{x\in \mathbb Q: x^2\lt 2\}$ doesn't have supremum in $\mathbb Q$ but for some reason that number looks very artificial to me that is, like some sort of trick which one might forget in future.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh:And this is not to say or claim that only rationals can't prove the theorem in my post. But sure, I'll work on it. I strongly believe with the dense nature of $\mathbb Q$, a proof only with rationals can be constructed.

Comment: Obviously rationals are sufficient to prove that and you will enjoy it. I don't want to give you an impossible task. :D

Answer (score 1):

$E$ is bounded.

$E$ is clopen in $\mathbb{Q}$  with the subspace topology because $E=((-\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{2}) \cup(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Also note that there isn't a rational $x$ for which $x^2=2$ or $x^2=3$, so $E$ can also be written as $E=([-\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{2}] \cup[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. But $E$ isn't closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Take any irrational number between $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ any neighborhood of that point will contain infinitely many points of $E$.

E isn't open in $\mathbb{R}$ because $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$ will contain infinitely irrationals as well so $(x-\delta, x+\delta) $ is not properly contained in $E$.

$E$ isn't compact because it's not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. For showing non-compact you don't have to assume nested sets. Just take $\frac{1}{m} < \min\{\frac{1}{n_1}, \frac{1}{n_2}, \cdots, \frac{1}{n_k}\}$ and then choose an $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2 <x^2 <2+\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: Isn't $E$ equal to $((-\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{2}) \cup (\sqrt{2} , \sqrt{3})) \cap \mathbb Q$ and therefore open in $\mathbb Q$ with respect to the subspace topology?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I misread that. Now corrected it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :). Please see my revised post.